# Help needed to Understand a Number Theory Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, and suppose that $x$ is an integer such that
$x^2 \equiv-2$ ( mod $p$ ). By considering the numbers $u + vx$ for various pairs $(u,v),$ show that at least one of the equations $a^2 + 2b^2 =p, a^2 + 2b^2=2p$ has a solution.

I don't get what this question means. I understand that $p$ is a prime number, and  $x$ is an integer such that $x^2 = -2$ ( mod $p$ ). Next, they are asking to consider the numbers of the form $u + vx.$ Next, is the point where the problem occurs i.e now they ask us to show that at least one of the equations $a^2 + 2b^2 =p, a^2 + 2b^2=2p$ has a solution. But solutions in what, in $a,b$ ? If it is, are they asking us to show that there exists $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$ for each $x$ such that $(u_1+v_1x,u_2+v_2x)$ is a solution of at least one of the equations $a^2 + 2b^2 =p, a^2 + 2b^2=2p.$  Again, if this is the case, then things look overwhelming. I need some hints/help on how to proceed.

Comment: First of all, the second equation is unnecessary because if $a^2+2b^2=2p$ has a solution , then $a$ must be even , say $a=2k$, so $4k^2+2b^2 =2p$ , so $2k^2+b^2=p$ , so there is also a solution to the first equation.

Comment: @Peter Ok, but then how to do the problem? Did I understand the problem correctly?

Comment: I do not understand how the hint should be helpful. The only proof I am aware of is based on infinite descent , but it is not easy.

Comment: @Peter If you show the method, I 'll be obliged!

Comment: See e.g. https://math.mit.edu/~desole/781/hw3.pdf at PDF page 2

Comment: For additional context: this is problem 56 in section 2.1 of Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery's "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers."  The somewhat oblique "By considering the numbers . . . for various pairs (u,v)" hint, which is present verbatim in the book, is likely an attempt to refer the reader to the textbook's proof of its Lemma 2.13, which precedes this problem by a few pages and uses a similar argument

Comment: @leslietownes Ok, but what about my understanding of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the question was:

> Let $p$ be a prime number, and suppose that $x$ is an integer such that
> $x^2 \equiv-2\pmod p.$ By considering the numbers $u + vx$ for various pairs $(u,v),$ show that at least one of the equations $a^2 + 2b^2 =p, a^2 + 2b^2=2p$ has a solution.

Let's analyze this question bit by bit. Firstly they asked, to

- denote $p$ as a prime number.
- Next, $x$ is an integer that satisfies $x^2\equiv -2\pmod p$ as mentioned.
- Next, they want us to consider the numbers, $u+xv$ where $u,v$ are any arbitrary pair of integers.
- For the final part, they wanted to mean, that at least one of the two equations, i.e $$a^2 + 2b^2 =p, a^2 + 2b^2=2p$$ in $a$ and $b$ has a solution $a=a_0$ and $b=b_0.$

The thing is you have mixed up the last point with the 2nd last point. But in fact, the first three points are telling some informations.

The last point (above) is in no way connected to the previous three. They just asked you to show that there exist some value of $a,b$ such that at least one of the two equations $a^2 + 2b^2 =p, a^2 + 2b^2=2p$ hold true. This $a,b$ can be any arbitrary but valid integer pair.

Now, they have linked the last point to the previous three by saying use the numbers, $u+vx$ for this purpose. What they mean, precisely that "Use the numbers $u+vx$ for showing that at least one of the equations $a^2 + 2b^2 =p, a^2 + 2b^2=2p$ has a solution. This is where the connection comes in. You can take this as a hint, i.e "Use these numbers..."

Without these information, it would have been difficult to show that there is indeed a solution to those two equations. We would have a hard time establishing it. But by using these numbers it becomes a simple task. Here is how:

We call those numbers as $f(u,v).$ Next, we define $K=\sqrt p.$

Now, $\sqrt p\not\in \Bbb Z.$ So, we have the strict inequality i.e $K\lt \sqrt p \lt K+1.$

We just assume that $0\leq u,v\leq K$ without any justification but just hope that this assumption will be a key to prove things. Also, this assumption does not affect any interest(s) of the given problem, so we are free to make such an assumption. Also because, taking this assumption preserves the generality of our  approach or solution. So, there is no harm, in making such an assumption, all in all.

Now, we can note that the total number of $f(u,v)$'s that we have in our hand has a one-to-one correspondence with the total number of pairs of $(u,v)$ possible under the prior assumption( i.e $0\leq u,v\leq K$ ). So, the total number of $f(u,v)$'s possible is $(K+1)^2$ as the total number of pairs of $(u,v)$ possible under the prior assumption that $0\leq u,v\leq K$ is $(K+1)^2.$

We now consider the remainders on dividing these $K+1$ numbers (or $f(u,v)'s$ ) by $p.$ The total number of remainders is $p.$ Also, as $\sqrt p\lt K+1\implies p\lt (K+1)^2$ we can conclude by Pigeon Hole Principle that two numbers (or $f(u,v)'s$ ) leave the same remainder on division by $p.$ Let them be $f(u_1,v_1)=u_1+v_1x$ and $f(u_2,v_2)=u_2+v_2x.$ So, $$u_1+v_1x\equiv u_2+v_2x  \pmod p\implies u_1-u_2\equiv -x(v_1-v_2)\pmod p.$$ Let $a=u_1-u_2$ and $b=v_1-v_2$. Then, $a\equiv -bx\pmod p\implies a^2\equiv b^2x^2\equiv -2b^2\pmod p$ as $x^2 \equiv-2\pmod p.$

Again, $u_1\lt K,u_2\gt 0\implies a\lt K.$ Now, as $u_1\gt 0, u_2\lt K$ we have, $a=u_1-u_2\gt -K$. Using these we can say, $|a|\lt K.$ Similarly, we can show that $|b|\lt K.$ Squaring and adding these two inequalities gives us, $a^2+2b^2=|a|^2+2|b|^2\lt 3K^2\lt 3p.$

So, we have found out that, $p|a^2+2b^2$ and $a^2+2b^2\lt 3p.$ The only possible multiples of $p$ in $[p,3p)$ are $p$ and $2p$. So, $a^2+2p^2=p$ or $a^2+2b^2=2p.$

Indeed, we have found that $a=u_1-u_2,b=v_1-v_2$ satisfies either one of the given equations in the original problem.

Notice, how we have used the numbers $u+vx$ to calculate or find out the solutions explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider pairs $(u, v)$ such that $0 \le u, v < \sqrt{p}$.  There are $([\sqrt{p}] + 1)^2 > p$ of such pairs.  Hence, there are two distinct pairs $(u_1, v_1)$, $(u_2, v_2)$ such that $u_1x + v_1 \equiv u_2x + v_2 \pmod{p} $.
Let $(b, a) = (u_1 - u_2, v_1 ​​- v_2)$.
Rewrite the congruence above
$$bx + a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
Notice, that
$$p \mid a^2 + 2b^2 = (a - bx)(a + bx) + b^2(x^2 + 2)$$
But $0 < |a|, |b|  < \sqrt{p}$.  Hence, $0 < a^2 + 2b^2 < 3p$.  Hence, $a^2 + 2b^2 = p$ or $a^2 + 2b^2 = 2p$.

Actually, this proof was invented by Lagrange when he proved the theorem on the representability of any prime $q \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ as $a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I think, this is an incomplete answer since I also asked for some clarifications regarding my understanding of the problem.